# HttpClient PostAsync - empty string becomes null string?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the HttpClient class to post data to an HTTP service.  So far, everything seems to work great, but I have noticed one situation in where things fail to work as I expect.  Suppose that the post that I'm doing requires several parameters, like so:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserId", userId.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmailAddress", emailAddress),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Details", details)
        });

    var result = await client.PostAsync("/api/SomeAPICall", content);

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Successfully made call.");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Call failed: " + result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if all the fields have valid values.  However, if the the emailAddress or details fields are an empty string, the Http post to the server will fail because they are required fields.  (The call results in an Bad Request response from the server).  Something, somewhere is converting my empty strings into null strings.

Is there any way to still make the call to the service work with an empty string?  Why is the empty string being converted to a null string?

Comment: Are you sure that the required field check doesn't simply reject a non-null empty string as not having a value provided?  I certainly wouldn't expect an empty string to be a valid value of a required field.

Comment: 1) `Everything works fine if all the fields have valid values`, then pass valid values. 2) There is no *hidden* code in .Net that converts your empty strings to null magically.

Comment: How are you performing validation? If with data annotations, by default `RequiredAttribute` rejects empty strings. To turn that check off, `Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)`.

Comment: L.B.: With the particular fields in question, being empty is fine.  I believe Cory and Servy are correct - validation is being done with a Required attribute. on the API side.  (It's an MVC 4 Web API that it's connecting to).  Cory's suggestion seems to make the most sense here.

Comment: Oddly enough, one of the other methods that was having this same issue is not marked as required.  In the KeyValuePair, the string is empty.  On the server side, inside the API call, the string that is received is null (as opposed to empty).  Thoughts?